# How can i manipulate date data before saving to the database in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a `Clutch` entity like this:

```
<?php

namespace Breedr\ClutchBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Clutch
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Clutch
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var Breedr\BreedingPairsBundle\Entity\Pairs
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Breedr\BreedingPairsBundle\Entity\Pairs")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="breeding_pair", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $breedingPair;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="laid_date", type="date")
     */
    private $laidDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="estimated_hatch_start", type="date")
     */
    private $estimatedHatchStart;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="estimated_hatch_end", type="date")
     */
    private $estimatedHatchEnd;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hatch_date", type="date")
     */
    private $hatchDate;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="egg_amount", type="integer")
     */
    private $eggAmount;

    /**
     * @var Breedr\UserBundle\Entity\User
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Breedr\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set breedingPair
     *
     * @param integer $breedingPair
     * @return Clutch
     */
    public function setBreedingPair($breedingPair)
    {
        $this->breedingPair = $breedingPair;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get breedingPair
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getBreedingPair()
    {
        return $this->breedingPair;
    }

    /**
     * Set laidDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $laidDate
     * @return Clutch
     */
    public function setLaidDate($laidDate)
    {
        $this->laidDate = $laidDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get laidDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getLaidDate()
    {
        return $this->laidDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set estimatedHatchStart
     *
     * @param \DateTime $estimatedHatchStart
     * @return Clutch
     */
    public function setEstimatedHatchStart($estimatedHatchStart)
    {
        $this->estimatedHatchStart = $estimatedHatchStart;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get estimatedHatchStart
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEstimatedHatchStart()
    {
        return $this->estimatedHatchStart;
    }

    /**
     * Set estimatedHatchEnd
     *
     * @param \DateTime $estimatedHatchEnd
     * @return Clutch
     */
    public function setEstimatedHatchEnd($estimatedHatchEnd)
    {
        $this->estimatedHatchEnd = $estimatedHatchEnd;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get estimatedHatchEnd
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEstimatedHatchEnd()
    {
        return $this->estimatedHatchEnd;
    }

    /**
     * Set hatchDate
     *
     * @param \DateTime $hatchDate
     * @return Clutch
     */
    public function setHatchDate($hatchDate)
    {
        $this->hatchDate = $hatchDate;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get hatchDate
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getHatchDate()
    {
        return $this->hatchDate;
    }

    /**
     * Set eggAmount
     *
     * @param integer $eggAmount
     * @return Clutch
     */
    public function setEggAmount($eggAmount)
    {
        $this->eggAmount = $eggAmount;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get eggAmount
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getEggAmount()
    {
        return $this->eggAmount;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param \Breedr\UserBundle\Entity\User $user
     * @return Clutch
     */
    public function setUser(\Breedr\UserBundle\Entity\User $user = null)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return \Breedr\UserBundle\Entity\User 
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }
}
```

And here is my `ClutchType` form:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $currentUser = $this->currentUser;
    $builder
        ->add('breedingPair', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'Breedr\BreedingPairsBundle\Entity\Pairs',
            'property' => 'getPairAsString',
            'placeholder' => 'Choose a breeding pair',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) use ($currentUser) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('br')
                    ->where('br.user = :currentUser')
                    ->orderBy('br.breedingPairDate')
                    ->setParameter('currentUser', $currentUser);
            }
        ))
        ->add('laidDate')
        ->add('estimatedHatchStart')
        ->add('estimatedHatchEnd')
        ->add('hatchDate')
        ->add('eggAmount')
    ;
}
```

Now, what I would like to do is not show `estimatedHatchStart` or `estimatedHatchEnd` on the front end, and use the data from `laidDate` to add 30 days and 40 days respectfully to give me the start and end hatch dates which will then be saved to database.

What is the best practice to do this? I have just read about the `FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT` event, but i am unsure if this is the correct way to go about it?

EDIT:

`setLaidDate` function:

```
/**
 * Set laidDate
 *
 * @param \DateTime $laidDate
 * @return Clutch
 */
public function setLaidDate($laidDate)
{
    $this->laidDate = $laidDate;

    $estimatedHatchStart = $laidDate->modify('+30days');
    $estimatedHatchEnd = $laidDate->modify('+40days');

    $this->setEstimatedHatchStart($estimatedHatchStart);
    $this->setEstimatedHatchEnd($estimatedHatchEnd);

    return $this;
}
```

`ClutchController`:

```
<?php

namespace Breedr\ClutchBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use Breedr\ClutchBundle\Entity\Clutch;
use Breedr\ClutchBundle\Form\ClutchType;

/**
 * Clutch controller.
 *
 */
class ClutchController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Lists all Clutch entities.
     *
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $this->getUser();
        $entities = $em
            ->getRepository('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch')
            ->findBy(array('user' => $user), array()
        );

        return $this->render('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch:index.html.twig', array(
            'entities' => $entities,
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Creates a new Clutch entity.
     *
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $entity = new Clutch();
        $entity->setUser($this->getUser());
        $form = $this->createCreateForm($entity);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($entity);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('clutch_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
        }

        return $this->render('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to create a Clutch entity.
     *
     * @param Clutch $entity The entity
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createCreateForm(Clutch $entity)
    {
        $currentUser = $this->getUser()->getId();

        $form = $this->createForm(new ClutchType($currentUser), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('clutch_create'),
            'method' => 'POST',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create'));

        return $form;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to create a new Clutch entity.
     *
     */
    public function newAction()
    {
        $entity = new Clutch();
        $form   = $this->createCreateForm($entity);

        return $this->render('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch:new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form'   => $form->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Finds and displays a Clutch entity.
     *
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Clutch entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch:show.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Displays a form to edit an existing Clutch entity.
     *
     */
    public function editAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Clutch entity.');
        }

        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return $this->render('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }

    /**
    * Creates a form to edit a Clutch entity.
    *
    * @param Clutch $entity The entity
    *
    * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
    */
    private function createEditForm(Clutch $entity)
    {
        $currentUser = $this->getUser()->getId();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ClutchType($currentUser), $entity, array(
            'action' => $this->generateUrl('clutch_update', array('id' => $entity->getId())),
            'method' => 'PUT',
        ));

        $form->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update'));

        return $form;
    }
    /**
     * Edits an existing Clutch entity.
     *
     */
    public function updateAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Clutch entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $editForm = $this->createEditForm($entity);
        $editForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($editForm->isValid()) {
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('clutch_edit', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        return $this->render('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch:edit.html.twig', array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        ));
    }
    /**
     * Deletes a Clutch entity.
     *
     */
    public function deleteAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($id);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entity = $em->getRepository('BreedrClutchBundle:Clutch')->find($id);

            if (!$entity) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Clutch entity.');
            }

            $em->remove($entity);
            $em->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('clutch'));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a form to delete a Clutch entity by id.
     *
     * @param mixed $id The entity id
     *
     * @return \Symfony\Component\Form\Form The form
     */
    private function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->setAction($this->generateUrl('clutch_delete', array('id' => $id)))
            ->setMethod('DELETE')
            ->add('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Delete'))
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with doing it straight in the entity.  For example

```
public function setLaidDate($date)
{
    $this->laidDate = $laidDate;

    $hatchDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+30 days"));
    $hatchDateEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+40 days"));

    $this->setEstimatedHatchStart($hatchDate);
    $this->setEstimatedHatchEnd($hatchDateEnd);

    return $this;
}
```

It would just mean that anytime `$this->setLaidDate()` is called the other two fields will also be updated.  You could also do this manually in the controller when you handle the form submission and before actually persisting the entity to the database.

Or my favorite way is making an entity manager.  A service you use to help you create new empty entities and persist existing ones back to the database.

```
#services.yml
services:
    my_custom_manager:
        class: AppBundle\Entity\MyEntityManager
        arguments: [ "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager" , 'AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity']
```

AppBundle/Entity/MyEntityManager

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity;


class MyEntityManager
{
    protected $class;
    protected $orm;
    protected $repo;

    public function __construct(ObjectManager $orm , $class)
    {
        $this->orm = $orm;
        $this->repo = $orm->getRepository($class);

        $metaData = $orm->getClassMetadata($class);
        $this->class = $metaData->getName();
    }

    public function create()
    {
        $class = $this->getClass();
        $myEntity = new $class;

        return $myEntity;
    }

    public function updateMyEntity(MyEntity $entity, $flush = true)
    {

        $date = $entity->getLaidDate();
        $hatchStart = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+30 days"));
        $hatchEnd = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . "+40 days"));

        $entity->setHatchStart($hatchStart);
        $entity->setHatchEnd($hatchEnd)

        $this->orm->persist($entity);
        if($flush)
        {
            $this->orm->flush();
        }
    }

    public function getClass()
    {
        return $this->class;
    }
}
```

And then in the controller

```
<?php

public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $manager = $this->get('my_custom_manager');

    $newEntity = $manager->create();

    $form = $this->createForm(new MyType() , $newEntity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if($form->isValid())
    {   
        $manager->updateMyEntity($newEntity);
    }

    //The rest of the code
}
```

Or another easy way would be to just set it all by hand in the controller action.  There's nothing wrong with that as well.  All up to you really.

**EDIT**

If I'm to believe your FormType, you still have

```
->add('estimatedHatchStart')
->add('estimatedHatchEnd')
```

So what's happening when the form submits in the background `$this->setLaidDate($date)` runs and your estimated hatches get set.  But then `$this->setEstimatedHatchStart($date)` and `$this->estimatedHatchEnd($date)` are getting called and likely set to `NULL` if you're leaving those fields in your form blank.  At least this is my guess.  Try removing the fields from the form and see if that works.

Comment: This is a great answer. If i do the first idea i get this error `Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string` (i also had to change `public function setLaidDate($date)` to `public function setLaidDate($laidDate)` by the way) - any ideas?

Comment: Sry had to drive home.  If it's already a datetime object you can just `$date->modify('+30 days')`  http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php  So basically `$hatchDateStart = $date->modify('+30days');  $this->setHatchStart($hatchStartDate);` and so on.

Comment: Haha that's okay. Okay so i've done what you've suggested and changed a couple variables as `$date` needs to be `$laidDate`. The problem is, when the form is submitted, the date's aren't being set in the database?

Comment: @AndyHolmes could you update your question with the code you're using in your controller and the new entity code?  Sorry about my slacker code.  I get lazy and hate typing long variable names lol.

Comment: Haha no problem, 2 seconds :)

Comment: Updated, let me know if i missed anything. It's at the bottom :)

Comment: I've already removed those from my FormType, still happening :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78361/discussion-between-andy-holmes-and-squeegy).